# MySQL C++ Connector: Get the insert_id

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using mysql connector C++. There is an auto_increament column in my table, I want to get the insert id when I perform an insert action. Does someone know how to get it? Thanks.

My code is something like:

```
conn->setAutoCommit(0);
pstmt.reset(conn->prepareStatement(insertStr.c_str()));

int updateCount = pstmt->executeUpdate();
conn->commit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the API of the library you are using does not provide a method to retrieve the last_insert_id (which seems to be the case for the C++ Connector) you can always do a query

> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

which gives you the "value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement." [See here for the explanation of MySQL's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

UPDATE:

I found [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?167,294960,295250#msg-295250) from a user who is saying the if you do not use auto_increment on your field you can use

> SELECT *@@identity* AS id;

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. I can get the inserted id with this way. One question, will it be conflict if there are many connections executing insert action?

Comment: It works on a per connection-basis. And even on a per Table-basis if you add `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM table`.