# C++ MySql get last inserted id

Tags: c++, mysql

I´m having the following code that insert a row into mysql database and return the inserted id:

```
    /*
     * Execute the statement
     */
    std::string sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE (A, B, C) VALUES (1, 2, 3)";

    sql::Statement *stmt;
    stmt = connection->createStatement();
    stmt->execute(sql);

    /*
     * Get the returned id
     */
    stmt = connection->createStatement();
    sql::ResultSet *res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT @@identity AS id");
    res->next();
    model.modelId = res->getInt64("id");
```

My questions are:

Do I really need to call `connection->createStatement()` again ? 
I think this may overload the code, as I need to call twice the database.

Is there a way to optimize this code ?

Is there other way to get the last inserted id ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried executing both queries at once separated by ;

Answer (score 4):

Just for the reference, `@@identity` is [MSSQL-specific system function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx), that also returns last-insert id but for MSSQL, not for MySQL.

To get last-insert id in MySQL, since you have asked specifically for MySQL, you need to change your SELECT statement to following:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id;
```

Also, since `stmt->execute()` and `stmt->executeQuery()` methods take *String*, as input argument, I am sure that you don't need to `connection->createStatement()` again. Just to confirm, I just googled it and found this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-query.html).

Please note that this answer is specifically for MySQL, as this question is about MySQL. Hope it helps.

Comment: Note:  The SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() function returns the ID of the last inserted item; if the item was not inserted, this will not return the expected value.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203691/mysql-c-connector-get-the-insert-id LAST_INSERT_ID() has problems on some cases, that´s why I used the SELECT @@identity AS id. The original questions about performance were not answered....